# Acceder a los elementos de una tupla y lista en python usando FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, python-requests, tuplas

Tengo declarado los siguientes modelos

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None


class Offer(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    items: List[Item]
```

Mi petición POST

Quiero acceder a los datos que tiene la propiedad items en Offer

```
@app.post("/offers/")
async def create_offer(offer: Offer):
    print("Tipo",type(offer)) --> Es de tipo <class 'model.Offer'>
     
    for i in offer:
        print("tipo i",type(i)) --> Es de tipo <class 'tuple'>
        for x in i:
            print("x TIPO",type(x)) --> Es de tipo <class 'list'>
            print("val",x[0])   -->resultado: name='Scrap 1' description='Scrap PCB' price=10.0 tax=2.4

    return offer
```

```
Ejemplo 
print("val",x[0])
-->Accedo y me traé por ejemplo: 
  name='Scrap 1' description='Scrap PCB' price=10.0 tax=2.4
```

Quiero acceder a name, description y price; sin embargo NO puedo hacerlo de las siguientes formas

```
x[name]  
x[description]
x['name']  
x['description']
```

Ya que X es una lista, solo puedo acceder de la siguiente forma: `x[0]`, pero ya no puedo acceder a name, description y price.

Comment: Has probado con ```x[0].name```?

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene `for i in offer:` o `for x in i:`? Accede a sus atributos, no iteres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es la iteración que estas haciendo no esta apuntando a la lista de `items` que quieres. Accede a la lista que pertenece al objeto que ya le estas pasando de tipo `Offer`:

```
@app.post("/offers/")
async def create_offer(offer: Offer):
     
    for item in offer.items:
            print(item.name, item.description, item.price, item.tax)

    return offer
```

Answer (score 2):

siguiendo tu ejemplo podrías acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
x[0]['name']
```